# Powershell Output Help

Tags: sql-server, powershell, csv

I have wriiten the following SQL script to execute using powershell.

```
    cls
foreach ($svr in get-content "demo.txt")
{
  $con = "server=MC1-PQ10X.RF.LILLY.COM\SQL01;database=mylilly_WSS_Content_INCTSK0014840;Integrated Security=sspi" 

  $cmd = "SELECT
Docs.DirName + '/' + Docs.LeafName AS 'Item Name',
DocVersions.UIVersion, 
(DocVersions.UIVersion/512) as Version_Label, DocVersions.Level, DocVersions.TimeCreated
FROM DocVersions FULL OUTER JOIN Docs ON Docs.Id = DocVersions.Id
--   INNER JOIN Webs On Docs.WebId = Webs.Id
--INNER JOIN Sites ON Webs.SiteId = SItes.Id
WHERE (DirName LIKE '%globalcontentrepository%')
AND (IsCurrentVersion = '0')
AND (DocVersions.Id IN ('$svr'))"

  $da = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter ($cmd, $con)

  $dt = new-object System.Data.DataTable

  $da.fill($dt) |out-null

  $dt | Export-Csv music.csv -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation

 }
```

The problem I'm facing with the above code is regarding the output. For every **$svr**, this code is creating a new csv file. The input file is containing around 1000 inputs. 
My requirement is that all the output should get stored in the file rather than creating new file.

Please look into this. Kindly give your suggestions.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried moving the output outside the loop, as mentioned in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9220445/4406684).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have it go to one file you have two options, and I think the first will get a little better performance than the second.

First you can simply add a parameter to the `Export-Csv` to append to the file. As long as the columns are consistent (the same) it should work with out issue.

```
$dt | Export-Csv music.csv -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Second, pull the contents of the `foreach` loop into a variable and then output it all at one time to the `Export-Csv`. This will will mean it will pull all of the data into memory and then output it all to the file. It depends on how much data you are pulling out but this may add on some time for the execution of the script.

```
$results = 
foreach ($svr in get-content "demo.txt")
{
  $con = "server=MC1-PQ10X.RF.LILLY.COM\SQL01;database=mylilly_WSS_Content_INCTSK0014840;Integrated Security=sspi" 

  $cmd = "SELECT
Docs.DirName + '/' + Docs.LeafName AS 'Item Name',
DocVersions.UIVersion, 
(DocVersions.UIVersion/512) as Version_Label, DocVersions.Level, DocVersions.TimeCreated
FROM DocVersions FULL OUTER JOIN Docs ON Docs.Id = DocVersions.Id
--   INNER JOIN Webs On Docs.WebId = Webs.Id
--INNER JOIN Sites ON Webs.SiteId = SItes.Id
WHERE (DirName LIKE '%globalcontentrepository%')
AND (IsCurrentVersion = '0')
AND (DocVersions.Id IN ('$svr'))"

  $da = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter ($cmd, $con)

  $dt = new-object System.Data.DataTable

  $da.fill($dt) |out-null

  $dt

 }

$results | Export-Csv music.csv -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation
```